# SELECT command denied to user (even though I have all privileges)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, hosting

I host on godaddy.com and after multiple calls they ensured me that I have done right everything when it comes to the database setup. The account "python" has all necessary rights to fulfil its purpose.

```
import mysql.connector as sql

mydb = sql.connect(
host = "***.***.***.***",
user = "python",
passwd = "*******",
db = "main"
)
print(mydb)
sql_select_Query = "select * from wp_posts.wp_content"
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(cursor.rowcount)
```

On phpmyadmin Im not able to do anything. I can't grant any rights. When I execute the code, the following error occurs.

```
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7fddb0053610>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 2.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'python'@'p579F3618.dip0.t-ipconnect.de' for table 'wp_content'
```

The connection is established, but the database doesn't grant any access. I have the right to login, but nothing more.

Solutions I tried, but that failed:

- godaddy support is clueless (they say it should work perfectly)
- granting me rights through phpmyadmin (don't have any privilege to do that)
- added my IP address into the Remote Hosting Option in cPanel (now im able to establish a connection, but nothing more)

Maybe helpful:
*On phpmyadmin im automatically logged in into an account that ends with @localhost. This account has the select privilege, but I can't access its password and therefore can't use it in python.*